# Strange bug with C character copying program

Tags: c, string, c-strings

I've created a simple program that takes two command line arguments(a char and a number), and prints the char however many times specify with the number to the screen.

Example:

> ./fstring a 4
>
> aaaa

It mostly works, but for some reason, with specific numbers there is weird input at the end.

> ./fstring a 8
>
> aaaaaaaa¼@
>
> ./fstring a 9
>
> aaaaaaaaa@
>
> ./fstring a 10
>
> aaaaaaaaaa@

The same pattern of weirdness happens with 40, 41 and 42, as well as 88, 89 and 90.. and so forth. It seems to happen in increments of forty starting at 8. Here's the code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void create_string(char chr, int times);


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    create_string(*argv[1], atoi(argv[2]));
    return 0;
}   

void create_string(char c, int t)
{
    char buf[t+1];

    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < t; ++i)
        buf[i] = c;

    printf("%s\n", buf);
}
```

I imagine it has something to do with buf, but I can't figure it out.

Comment: The `%s` format specifier expects a null terminated string as argument. That's how it knows when to stop writing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot about the terminating zero of strings. Write

```
for(i = 0; i < t; ++i)
    buf[i] = c;
buf[i] = '\0';
```